# How to set a docker container to run on system reboot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I'm new to Docker using docker Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825 on ubuntu server 18.04 LTS.

I can run my docker container with

```
sudo docker start container_name
```

But every time my server reboots I have to start manually the container. tried `docker run -dit --restart unless-stopped container_name` but I receive the error unable to find image error

```
Unable to find image 'container_name:latest' locally
```

Comment: Putting a `docker start {container_name}` (and not a `docker run`  ...) in a systemd service definition should be enough. See [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/systemd-essentials-working-with-services-units-and-the-journal) and [this](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2017/200/Tutorials-Systemd).

Comment: With `docker start`it runs but if my laptop power fails I have to re-run the commmand again

Comment: If you put the `docker start` in an enabled systemd service it will restart on boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your container with the new restart policy using:

```
docker update --restart=unless-stopped <container name>
```

Provided docker starts with your server (it seems like it does when you can start your container right after) this will be enough to have your container start with it.

`docker run` is used to create a new container from an image so if you want to create a new container with the restart policy set you can do like this:

```
docker run --restart=unless-stopped <image name:version>
```